# Ubuntu 16.04, trying to run two monitors, with Integrated Graphics and GPU

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

My current setup is that I have two identical monitors. One plugged into my motherboard (Skylake i5-6500K) using HDMI, and the other plugged into GTX 1060 using HDMI. Running it on Ubuntu 16.04. The setup works fine when I boot it on Windows, but does not work well when I try to run it on Ubuntu.

I have tried to install different nvidia drivers, but to no success. Right now, I am using Integrated graphics as my default in the BIOS and the OS does not seem to detect it. By selecting IGFX as default, everything seems fine except the second monitor stays black. When I choose the GPU for my default in the BIOS setting, it gives me the error that says I am running on low-graphics mode and both screens stay dark after that.

What I thought interesting was how xrandr does not see the second monitor, but lshw seems to detect it as shown below.

Output for xrandr:

```
:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
1920x1080     60.00*+
1680x1050     59.95  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      60.00  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x800      59.81  
1152x864      75.00  
1280x720      60.00  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
800x600       75.00    60.32  
640x480       75.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output for `sudo lshw -C display`

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:129 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

[image]
[image]

In my previous attemps, I have successfully used just the monitor hooked up to the GPU with the other monitor(connected to mainboard HDMI) staying dark. nvidia-settings displayed a lot more information than the first picture above, but only about one screen.

Also, please note that I do not have xorg.conf. I've read many issues regarding this and many say to edit/investigate xorg.conf.

```
:~$ ls -l /etc/X11
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  1 19:31 app-defaults
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 22  2014 cursors
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    18 Oct 22  2014 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Oct 22  2014 fonts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17394 Dec  3  2009 rgb.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    13 Oct  9  2015 X -> /usr/bin/Xorg
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jun  1 19:31 xinit
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun 23  2014 xkb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   600 Sep 24 17:57 xorg.conf.09242016
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   600 Sep 25 21:23 xorg.conf.09252016
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   600 Sep 25 09:49 xorg.conf-backup160925094923
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   270 Sep 25 21:28 xorg.conf.failsafe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Sep 25 10:06 xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   709 Apr  1  2010 Xreset
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  1 19:30 Xreset.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  1 19:30 Xresources
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3730 Jan 29  2014 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep 25 09:05 Xsession.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   265 Jul  1  2008 Xsession.options
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 29  2015 xsm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   601 Oct 22  2014 Xwrapper.config
```

Comment: Running both from the Nvidia card would probably save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Your motherboard does not allow for simultaneous use, hence the need to select the default graphics in "BIOS" (UEFI actually). In Windows the Nvidia driver may allow the use of the integrated PORT but the actual card in use is Nvidia. The Nvidia driver for Linux most likely not. Again, connect both to the Nvidia card. You may need to properly install the Nvidia proprietary drivers because there's a chance you made a mess already with the subsequent installation attempts not cleaning up old drivers properly.